# How to loop through category group and identify those related to entry

Tags: entries, categories

Looping through a category group to show links to all the categories. This is an entry page and I want to highlight any categories assigned to the entry. How do I do that? I've tried this so far:

```
{% set cats = craft.categories.group('events').find() %}
{% for cat in cats %}
    <a href="{{ cat.url }}" {% if cat.relatedTo(entry) %}class=active{% endif %}>{{ cat.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your solution looks like it's almost there, but it would be making a lot of DB queries as Craft will be querying the database for each category. You can give Craft all the help you can with something like this.

```
{# First, retrieve all of your events categories #}
{% set cats = craft.categories.group('events').find() %}

{# Get the IDs of all categories related to this entry #}
{% set relatedCats = craft.categories.group('events').relatedTo({sourceElement: entry}).ids() %}

{# Test if the current category ID is in the array of related category IDs #}
{% for cat in cats %}
    <a href="{{ cat.url }}" {% if cat.id in relatedCats %}class="active"{% endif %}>{{ cat.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Works a treat. I know cat.relatedTo(entry) wasn't working, but, if it was, why would that have meant more DB queries? Is it because entry.relatedTo(cat) would query the DB each time?

Comment: Yeah, exactly Clive. Relations between element types (like entries and categories) are stored in a DB table. When you call `.relatedTo()`, Craft has to build a query to search this. Because you're calling `.relatedTo()` within a loop, the database will be queried for every category you iterate over, and the queries can be quite big.